# Oracle trigger to update phone numbers

Tags: oracle, triggers

Phone numbers are sent to our DB from a web service in this format:

```
1-210-5551212
```

I'd like for them to be input into the field like this if the first two characters are '1-':

```
1-210-555-1212
```

How would I create a on insert or update trigger to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your format from the web-service stays constant, you can do this.

```
CREATE TABLE PHONE_NUMBERS(PH_ID NUMBER(12), PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR2(20));


   CREATE OR replace TRIGGER trg_test_numbers 
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON phone_numbers 
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    IF Substr(:new.phone_number, 1, 2) = '1-' THEN 
      :new.phone_number := Substr(:new.phone_number, 1, 9) 
                           || '-' 
                           || Substr(:new.phone_number, 10); 
    END IF; 
END trg_test_numbers; 

insert into phone_numbers(ph_id, phone_number) VALUES(1,'1-210-5551212');
SELECT * from phone_numbers;
```

Comment: After some slight modifications it worked as promised. Thanks.