# Oracle trigger for Phone formatting

Tags: oracle, triggers

Previous question: 
[Oracle trigger to update phone numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847315/oracle-trigger-to-update-phone-numbers)

If the old value already has a '-' in position 10, it still adds it.
How would I fix this code to not do that?

```
CREATE OR replace TRIGGER fix_cell_phone 
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON CLIENTS_AND_FACILITATORS
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    -- Only do this for US Cell numbers
    IF SUBSTR(:new.CLI_SECOND_ADDRESS_DESC, 1, 2) = '1-' THEN 
      :new.CLI_SECOND_ADDRESS_DESC := 
                           SUBSTR(:new.CLI_SECOND_ADDRESS_DESC, 1, LENGTH(:new.CLI_SECOND_ADDRESS_DESC)-4) 
                           || '-' 
                           || SUBSTR(:new.CLI_SECOND_ADDRESS_DESC, LENGTH(:new.CLI_SECOND_ADDRESS_DESC)-3);
    END IF; 
END fix_cell_phone;
```

Comment: Strip all the formatting before you start adding any back in. Will you only have dashes, or might you need to strip spaces? Removing any non-numeric characters is probably the safest thing to do? I'd probably start with a plain number and then split it all three places you want the dashes to appear - after the 1 (if there is one; maybe you want to add it if there isn't?), after the NPA, and after then in position 10. Not sure how far you want to go with this though. Another approach is store store the plain number and add the formatting back for display, or in a virtual column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the '-' concatenation to use a CASE statement to conditionally concatenate the dash only if one does not already exist in the tenth position. Replace the assignment statement to your column with:

```
SUBSTR(:new.CLI_SECOND_ADDRESS_DESC, 1, LENGTH(:new.CLI_SECOND_ADDRESS_DESC)-4) 
|| CASE when SUBSTR(:new.CLI_SECOND_ADDRESS_DESC, 10, 1) <> '-' THEN '-' END 
|| SUBSTR(:new.CLI_SECOND_ADDRESS_DESC, LENGTH(:new.CLI_SECOND_ADDRESS_DESC)-3)
```